# Prevent employees from using anything else but my proprietary application

Tags: software, macos

I will be getting several mac minis for different branches that will have installed my software application which I need my employees to use. I need to make sure of the following:

- When the computer starts for my application to be on in full screen mode
- For the user to not be able to exit the app
- For the user to not be able to start plugging in their personal usb sticks and try to hack/view movies on the computer - one solution would be to lock the computer away and expose only the touchscreen graphic display. I suppose if my application automatically covers the full screen then the user would not be able to go into the finder app and browse through their files.

Most elegant solution is preferable, as long as the solution gets the job done effectively without any round about ways to by pass this setup.

Comment: @Mark I don't wish to turn the computer nodes into an internet hub for web content; please read my question properly. It is for my one software which will be installed on each computer which the employees must use with no access to anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You will likely want to look at the Parental Controls (System Preferences). While it won't prevent them from moving around in OS X, it will prevent them from running other applications that you have not explicitly authorized.

[image]

A detailed view rundown can be found here: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-limit-the-capabilities-of-a-user-in-mac-os-.html

Comment: hm this is a good start cksum, surely there must be a way to automatically start up a custom application of mine on login right and to just have it set on full screen mode without the user being able to close the application?

Comment: @Pavan I know you can launch an app on start up. That's easy enough. But I don't know a way to disable the chrome controls (minimize, maximize, etc.), or block access to peripheral ports. Although you may be able to kill a daemon that controls listening for new devices, maybe.

Comment: I dont understand why google chrome controls are being mentioned.. this has nothing to do with the web browser? The custom application I am talking about is not a web application through some web portal accessible online, instead its an application that I have developed for the Mac OS X. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Paven, window chrome has nothing to do with Google's browser. It's a design term denoting to the controls (and accompanying UI) of a window. You didn't want them being able to close or minimize your application, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Thank you for the kind explanation, its appreciated!